How to fix .net maui actool exited with code 1 error
I'm getting the following 3 errors when I build my MAUI application to iOS simulator (no issues deploying to android simulator):
actool exited with code 1

arch exited with code 1

The operation couldn't be completed. Failed to locate any simulator runtime matching options: {
BuildVersionString = 21F77;
Platforms = (
   "com.apple.platform.iphonesimulator"
);
VersionString = "17.5";
}

This is happening for any/all MAUI apps for me--I created a brand new app, made no changes, and it still happens.
What I've tried:

I saw this thread, however I have not changed the icon name, so this isn't the issue.
I tried adding the property group conditions raised here. However same errors showed up, pasting in property groups below:

attempt 1:
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'=='net8.0-ios'">
    <ForceSimulatorX64ArchitectureInIDE>true</ForceSimulatorX64ArchitectureInIDE>
  </PropertyGroup>

attempt 2:
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'=='net8.0-ios'">
    <RuntimeIdentifier>iossimulator-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
  </PropertyGroup>


Have a look Unable to debug on iPhone Device & Can't distribute MAUI iOS App to app store

Did your Xcode update? Did you launch Xcode to see if it wants to install some runtime first?

Answer is here. Needed to download 17.5 on xcode even though wasn't pushing to an ios simulator.
